# Инсталлятор для программы

Tags: c#, установка

Сейчас моя программа работает портативно — просто распаковываем архив в папку и запускаем. Есть кустарный инсталлятор, который скачивает нужный архив (x32 или x64) и распаковывает в указанную папку. Этот же кустарный инсталлятор используется для обновления программы.

Я хочу, чтобы пользователь скачивал инсталлятор, который будет создавать папку в Programm Files\MySoft, записывать в нее только uninstall.exe, а так же папку Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MySoft записывать в нее кустарный инсталлятор программы и запускать его, передавая ему последующую установку.

Так же хотелось бы, чтобы инсталлятор мог ассоциировать расширения файлов и делать ярлык на exe.

Если это важно, то программа написана под .Net 4 на C# в VS12.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Хорошо, вы хотите сделать так, так и так. А в чём проблема?

Comment: Да, вы правы, я забыл сформулировать вопрос, собственно, я хотел услышать советы как это можно организовать "малой кровью".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В Visual Studio есть Setup project. Setup project может автоматически включать  .NET framework в установочный пакет:

Тут по шаговое инструкция :

1. Создать проект установшика. Можете пользоватся Setup Wizard ом.

   [image]
2. Выберите тип проекта.

   [image]
3. Выберите что выводить.

   [image]
4. Нажимаем Завершить (Finish).
5. Открываем свойства Проекта Установшика.

   [image]
6. Выбераем включить  .NET framework.

   [image]
7. Компилируем (Build) проект установшик
8. Проверям что получилось

   [image]

---

**Заметка:** Возможно The Visual Studio Installer projects нету в вашем  Visual Studio.  Но, Visual Studio 2013 вы можете скачать его с `Tools > Extensions and Updates > Online (search) > Visual Studio Installer Projects`